# How to display the parent category if only the child category has been chosen

Tags: categories, loop

I want the user to tick the child cat only, but I'd like to be able to display the parent cat based on the child cat. This is within the loop.

Answer (score 1):

There's a function called [`get_category_parents`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_parents/) that will return a list of parents based on the ID. You can then loop through this list to display the parents.

Comment: I tried `<?php echo get_category_parents( $cat, true, '  ' ); ?>` but it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe `$cat` is a term object? Try `$cat->term_id`.

Comment: Yeah, that example in the codex doesn't work. You cannot echo a list. You'll have to loop through it.

Comment: General tip if echoing doesn't work. Use `var_dump` to see the structure of the variable you are trying to print. That will tell you how to dissect it in order to echo it.

Comment: `<?php echo get_category_parents( $cat->term_id, true, ' ' ); ?>` didn't work either. I'm not very familiar with php.

Answer (score 0):

`get_category_parents()` is a function which returns the category's parent **based** on the cat ID.
So in this case to make it adaptable, we use `get_queried_object_id()` which will output the cat ID (**number**) of current object.

It's as simple as :

```
$parents = get_category_parents( get_queried_object_id());
if ( ! is_wp_error( $parents )) echo $parents;
```

It's good practice to implement the **WP_Error** fallback, mostly to avoid abritratry code execution.

A little **PHP** breakdown for those beginning:

1. we declare the variable `$parents`
2. `$parents` will equal everything between the "**=**" sign and next semi-colon "**;**"
3. `get_queried_object_id()` returns the current object id (current category number)
4. That number is piped in `get_category_parents()` -> **i.e get_category_parents('26')**
5. Last function returns name category 26 parent's name -> say 'Master Category' for example
6. Semi-colon ! So end of this 'loop', simple way to think of it :

`$parents = get_category_parents(26)` -> `$parents = 'Master Category'`

i'll quickly breeze through the last part, you're all smart cookies eager to figure it all out on your own ;)

7. **if** `$parents` doesn't equal `wp_error` **echo** `$parents`

End of story !

Comment: unfortunately `<?php $parents = get_category_parents( get_queried_object_id());
if ( ! is_wp_error( $parents )) echo $parents; ?>` didn't display anything?

Comment: can you provide the code of page you placed it in, what loop it's in?

Comment: It's just in a normal single.php loop.

Comment: the following will only work for single content page, otherwise i suggest using a hook in the functions file. In the file **/content/parts/content-single.php** of your theme folder, `<?php the_category(',&nbsp; &nbsp;'); ?>` replace by `<?php $category = get_the_category(); $first_category = $category[0]; echo sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', get_category_link( $first_category ), $first_category->name );?>`